# Running a command without ./

Tags: osx, bash, docker

I am trying to understand something that might be very simple for a lot of you but is quite puzzling from me as a daily Windows user.

I am following the [docker installation](http://docs.docker.io/installation/mac/) on Mac OS X.

One of the steps is:

```
$ chmod +x boot2docker
```

The next step is using boot2docker like this:

```
$ boot2docker init
```

However this does not work for me. What works is:

```
 $ ./boot2docker init
```

So the tutorial assumes that I need to implicitly run with `./` or is there a way in bash to avoid typing that and execute something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that Windows implicitly has `.` in the path, which is something it inherited from DOS, which always was a single user system.

Mac OS X is build on Unix, which is a multi user system. And for security reasons it does not have `.` implicitly in the path.

When `.` is not in the path, then to run a command in the current directory, one has to prefix the command with `./` in order to explicitly tell the shell, that you want to run a command in the current directory. The `./` notation will work with or without `.` in the path. If you remove `./` it will only work if `.` is in the path. For that reason documentation will usually include the `./` part.

What is the security implication of including `.` in the path?

Let's say that you have typed `cd ~joker` to enter `joker`'s home directory. Next you type `ls` to see what files are there. If `.` was at the beginning of the path, then `joker` could have a script in his home directory called `ls`, which could do anything to your user account.

If `.` was the last entry in the path, it wouldn't go so bad. In the previous scenario, you would run the real `ls` command instead of the one `joker` had in his home directory. But you might mistype the `ls` command. Your fingers might slip, and you typed `ks`. Then `ks` might not be found any of the preceding directories, but finally as the shell got to `.` it might find a `ks` command in `joker`'s home directory.

Comment: Ok so the tutorial from docker not using ./is not best thing for beginners :)

Comment: @Cris Either that or they should have mentioned adding the newly created bin directory to PATH, if that is what they had in mind.